# Cant serve pages created with Yii framework on localhost on Mac

Tags: macos, yii, http-status-code-403

I had a website I designed in the Yii framework. I had to move it over to a new Mac because the old one was dying. I moved everything over, but I cannot access the webpages from the browser, I get a 403 forbidden error. I CHMOD'ed the files to see if that would help, but to no avail. I cannot seem to find the answer on the Yii forums, either. Seems NO files on this site can be accessed even though file permissions are wide open. I cannot seem to find anything in htaccess or httpd that helps. Any ideas on how I tell Yii/Apache that it's ok to serve these pages?

EDIT:

So I see this in the apache2 error_log file:

Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /Users/me/Sites/website/index.php

Weird. When I uploaded the site from my old computer to the web I never got any 403s but on this mac only I get this.

Comment: What does the URL manager section of your config file look like?

Comment: What is listed in your access/error log?

Comment: Thomas, I figured it out by checking the error log and seeing my user account was prohibited from using FollowSymLinks. Feel free to post an answer and I will check it.